# How to toggle hide/show a button based on the focus between 2 other HTML inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a login section, with I want to achieve something new:

When a user puts the focus on email or password input, the button should show 'LOGIN', When none of them has the focus, the text should be 'NOT A USER YET?'

The problem is I can't handle it properly when email loses focus and password input has the focus right after.

[image]
<sub>(source: [firefoxusercontent.com](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/ad713ee4-73ac-4053-9c29-8b0c7833130a.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [firefoxusercontent.com](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/a3d87680-a6e9-41c7-97e9-adde94d329da.png))</sub>

here is what I have tried so far:

> The design doesn't matter, just the functionality in js

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" style="width: 120px;height:25px;line-height: 1.1;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 0;border-radius: 3px 0 0 0" class="input-xs form-control lg_email no-shadow-on-focus">

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width: 120px;height:25px;line-height: 1.1;position: absolute;left: 0;top: 25px;border-radius: 0 0 0 3px" class="input-xs form-control lg_psw no-shadow-on-focus">

    <button type="submit" style="width:80px;text-align: center;font-size: 15px;height:50px;line-height: 25px;border-left: none;background-color: blue;display: none;position: absolute;right: 0;top:0;border-radius: 0" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary bgLogin">LOGIN</button>

    <button class="f-11 btn bgUser btn-primary" style="width:80px;text-decoration: none;height: 50px;position: absolute;right: 0;top:0;border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0"><span style="letter-spacing: 2px" class="f-13">NOT A</span><br> user yet ? </button> 

</form>
```

JS

```
setInterval(function(){
    if($(".lg_email").is(":focus") || $(".lg_psw").is(":focus")){
        $(".bgLogin").show();
        $(".bgUser").hide();
    }else{
        $(".bgLogin").hide();
        $(".bgUser").show();
    }
},500);
```

This way, the action wait for a little bit to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
$(function()
{

    $(".lg_email, .lg_psw").on('focus',function()
    {
       $(".bgLogin").show();
       $(".bgUser").hide();
    });


    $(".lg_email, .lg_psw").on('blur',function()
    {
         $(".bgLogin").hide();
         $(".bgUser").show();
    });
});
```

This way your using direct events rather than having to use an interval.

Comment: you're missing comma between lg_email and lg_psw

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/mzvarik/f6g8bau5/

Also don't use `<form action="">` but just `<form>`, it used to be buggy years ago, but it's just not needed if it's empty.

Comment: thanks for the advice! and yours works as well, but I will mark the first answer as accepted since both works